# How does Microdata rdfa compare to JSON-LD?

Tags: data, json, seo, w3c

The bottom of the Wikipedia "talk" page says that Microdata is dead, and superseded by rdfa and json-ld.

What is the difference between the formats (or value), and which one should be used?

I'm mostly interested in SEO for Google Shopping, and contact sharing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Microdata is not dead. While Microdata will not become a W3C standard¹, it’s still [part of WHATWG’s HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html#microdata).

#### Differences between JSON-LD, Microdata, and RDFa

(in the context of HTML documents)

**Microdata** and **RDFa** are conceptually similar: both syntaxes define attributes that get added to your existing HTML elements.

**JSON-LD** is a syntax that gets added to a `script` element ([used as data block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30798784/1591669), not as script), separately from your existing markup.

So the primary difference between Microdata/RDFa and JSON-LD is that you have to repeat the content if using JSON-LD, while you can² mark up your existing content if using Microdata/RDFa.

These three snippets convey the same structured data (a [`Person`](http://schema.org/Person) with a [`name`](http://schema.org/name) of "Alice"):

```html
<!-- Microdata -->

<p itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  Hi, I’m <span itemprop="name">Alice</span>.
</p>
```

```html
<!-- RDFa -->

<p vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Person">
  Hi, I’m <span property="name">Alice</span>.
</p>
```

```html
<!-- JSON-LD -->

<p>
  Hi, I’m Alice.
</p>

<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
   "@context": "http://schema.org",
   "@type": "Person",
   "name": "Alice"
  }
</script>
```

#### Which to use?

**JSON-LD** if you want to add a blob of structured data, without having to care about existing markup. Might be easier for tools that don’t support structured data (and you use other tools to generate/add it), or when copy-pasting ready-made snippets.

**Microdata/RDFa** if you want to make use of your existing markup (so you don’t have to duplicate the content → [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)). Might be easier if adding it by hand, or when tools already support it (like Drupal).

If deciding between Microdata and RDFa: I [recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14501684/1591669) to use RDFa instead of Microdata, primarily because of the [differences outlined in this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669).

RDFa and JSON-LD are both W3C Recommendations and both are RDF serializations.

---

For reference: an [older related answer about Microformats vs. Microdata vs. RDFa / Schema.org](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/166669/63183).

¹ At least not in the foreseeable future. https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/ became a *W3C Working Group Note* in 2013 (https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/), so it no longer gets updated/edited, and it will not become a *W3C Recommendation*.

² Of course Microdata/RDFa would allow to do something similar to JSON-LD: instead of marking up existing content, you could add `meta`/`link` elements that repeat the content. Bad practice, but possible.

Comment: Currently (July 2017), Google recommends unsing JSON-LD "wherever possible": https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data

Comment: Do I understand right, JSON-LD can only let you specify general info about whole page, but you can't express which exactly parts of the webpage correspond to which object in JSON-LD? Like, if you have a list of books, you can specify in JSON-LD that this page shows a list of books, but you won't be able to tell which of the books described in the JSON-LD correspond to which exactly element on the webpage? If so, Microdata/RDFa have one more important advantage: providing context to screenreaders used by blind people, but maybe I'm missing something in how JSON+LD works.

Comment: @Klesun: Correct, with JSON-LD, there is no native way to connect the HTML elements with the JSON-LD statements. But even with Microdata and RDFa, the HTML is just the carrier. Microdata/RDFa parsers will just extract the statements, without any coupling to the HTML. I suppose it could be conceivable for user agents (like screen readers) to use Microdata/RDFa to get more context about the HTML, but AFAIK no one does that yet, and Microdata/RDFa were not designed for this to begin with.

Comment: in the case of JSON-LD, why not using anchors to connect HTML elements? Or is it too cumbersome?

Comment: @Ooker I had similar thoughts. You could adopt that convention. However, many people have not adopted the convention. A tool parsing the file would not know if such convention is followed. Sometimes it would be followed & sometimes not. I wonder what % of implementations fully or partially couple the DOM Element's id with the schema Element's id.